# How to make synaptic use default browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, synaptic, default-browser

My default browser is Firefox, but when I click on a link "visit homepage" inside synaptic it opens the link in Chrome instead.

How do I make it open links in the default browser instead?

Answer (score 2):

The solution *appears* to be described in [this post](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?p=476492&sid=c1faf240781ca3b34b194fe21a865816#p476492) on the thread, [synaptic failed to execute default web browser. Input/output error](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=47695) (note that I have modified the links to give clearer contexts and fixed the third broken link):

> within synaptic, `onClick` handler for the homepage link is
> `RGPkgDetailsWindow::cbOpenHomepage()` (see [rgpkgdetails.cc - Line
> 201](https://github.com/mvo5/synaptic/blob/5285d4456e1bd3706290c96b330ed6a604937aa3/gtk/rgpkgdetails.cc#L201)) which calls `GetBrowserCommand()` (see [rgutils.cc - Line 114](https://github.com/mvo5/synaptic/blob/5285d4456e1bd3706290c96b330ed6a604937aa3/gtk/rgutils.cc#L114))
> and invokes `/usr/bin/xdg-open` (it is an easily patched shell script)
> (see [xdg-open.in - Line 432](https://sources.debian.org/src/xdg-utils/1.1.3-1+deb10u1/scripts/xdg-open.in/#L432))
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BROWSER" ]; then
>     open_envvar "$1"
> fi
> ```
>
> Patching here will guard against anything routed through `xdg-open`
> (not just synaptic)
>
> ```
> if [ -n "$BROWSER" ]; then
>     if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
>         open_envvar "su -c ${SUDO_USER} $1"
>     else
>         open_envvar "$1"
>     fi
> fi
> ```

The reason behind this is nicely described by [this post](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?p=476388&sid=c1faf240781ca3b34b194fe21a865816#p476388) on the same thread:

> The mystery of the observation your are facing is due to security
> settings and different users involved.
>
> Background: When you start synaptic, the GUI-app is run as user root.
> The problem: When you click on a link to open a web-browser, synaptic
> forwards the call to open a webbrowser as user root. This has certain
> system-security and stability related implications.
>
> Further : Synaptic can be started in different ways to run as user
> root, those different calls do have different system-security related
> constrains. (It can be called either via pkexec, gksu or gksudo,
> depending how the synaptic call is initiated, e.g from the menu, from
> MX-updater or something else.) Setting the default browser, within
> preferred applications or the through the debians alternative
> mechanism, is not sorting the issue provided by those
> security-constrains.
>
> Summary: As it is now the simplest way would be the copy the link and
> open the browser manually. This needs to get further considerations to
> provide a stable and secure way of calling from a GUI-app (running as
> user root) the users web-browser within the user environment.

This is probably worth noting that the patch could be *further modified*, as per the [final post](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?p=476517&sid=c1faf240781ca3b34b194fe21a865816#p476517):

> Nice idea to "secure" `xdg-open` a bit, probaly also worth to check it for all types of root-app invocations like, su-to-root, gksu, gksudo and pkexec, as we have f.i. in the menu a synapic-pkexec call.